# Why is this class that does not declare any pure virtual member function abstract?

Tags: c++, abstract-class, virtual-functions, pure-virtual, pspsdk

How is the following class `Game` abstract? And how do I make it concrete so I can create an instance of it?

game.h

```
#include <JApp.h>
#include <JGE.h>

class Game: public JApp
{    
private: 
    JGE* Engine;
    int x, y, x2, y2;
public:
    Game(JGE *engine);
    virtual ~Game();
    virtual void Create();
    virtual void Destroy();
    virtual void Update();
    virtual void Render();
};
```

main.cpp

```
//Other headers
#include "game.h"
int main(void)
{
    JGE* engine = NULL;
    SetupCallbacks();
    engine = JGE::GetInstance();
    engine->printf("Starting Game!");
    Game* g = new Game(engine); // Error 'Game is an abstract type 
    engine->SetApp(g);
    engine->Run();
    engine->Destroy();

    sceKernelExitGame();
}

Game::Game(JGE* engine) : JApp(engine)
{
    Engine = engine;
    x = 0;
    x2 = 100;
    y = 0;
    y2 = 100;
}
void Game::Update()
{
    if (this->Engine->GetButtonClick(PSP_CTRL_UP))
    {
        x2 += 1;
        y2 += 1;

    }
    else if(this->Engine->GetButtonClick(PSP_CTRL_DOWN))
    {

        y2 += 10;
        y += 10;
    }
}
void Game::Create()
{    
}
void Game::Render()
{
     JRenderer* renderer = JRenderer::GetInstance();
     renderer->DrawLine(x, y, x2, y2, ARGB(0, 0, 0, 255));
}
Game::~Game()
{       
}
void Game::Destroy()
{   
}
```

P.S. Any explanation will be helpful since I am not an expert in object-oriented programming.

Here is the error message together with some other stuff:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: PSP Pong, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  psp-g++ -I. -Ic:/pspsdk/psp/sdk/include -O2 -G0 -Wall  -I. -Ic:/pspsdk/psp/sdk/include -O2 -G0 -Wall  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -D_PSP_FW_VERSION=150   -c -o main.o main.cpp
1>  main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
1>main.cpp(57): error : cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Game'
1>  game.h (5) : note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Game':
1>  c:/pspsdk/psp/sdk/include/JApp.h (78) : note:   virtual void JApp::Pause()
1>  c:/pspsdk/psp/sdk/include/JApp.h (84) : note:   virtual void JApp::Resume()
1>  main.cpp: In constructor 'Game::Game(JGE*)':
1>main.cpp(66): error : no matching function for call to 'JApp::JApp(JGE*&)'
1>  c:/pspsdk/psp/sdk/include/JApp.h (26) : note: candidates are: JApp::JApp()
1>  c:/pspsdk/psp/sdk/include/JApp.h (22) : note:                 JApp::JApp(const JApp&)
1>  c:\pspsdk\bin\make: *** [main.o] Error 1
1>  Press any key to continue . . . 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(38,5): error MSB3073: The command "c:\pspsdk\bin\vsmake.bat" exited with code -1.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: `JApp` probably has some pure virtual functions that you're not overriding.

Comment: Maybe there is something in JApp that makes it abstract?

Comment: Is JApp abstract?  Did you override all of its pure virtual functions?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`JApp` has pure virtual functions you must implement in your class. Since you have not implemented them, your class is incomplete.

Sample to illustrate the problem:

```
struct B
{
    // this function is pure-virtual and
    // must be implemented in order to instantiate
    virtual void fn() = 0;
};

struct C : public B
{
    // missing implementation of fn().
    // as of now, this class is abstract because fn()
    // has no definition.
};

...

// try to instantiate...
C myobj;// this line produces error C2259: 'C' : cannot instantiate abstract class
```

Comment: That would cause a linker error, not a compiler error, though.

Comment: I was assuming you were talking about defining the functions.  If you're talking about not declaring all the necessary overrides in the class body, then I agree.

Comment: It causes a compiler error upon instantiation. Adding code sample.

Comment: @tenfour Thanks I realized I forgot to implement Pause and Resume.

Comment: It's incorrect to say the class is incomplete. The class simply cannot be instantiated because it's abstract. Incomplete type is [specifically defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type) in the language. Abstract classes are not incomplete.